# How to handle this CSS issue with Wordpress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a (probably not) unique issue with a css background div I am seeking advice on. I am using Wordpress, which creates my pages dynamically. The front page and some other pages are using one type of background (Gradient) while internal pages are using a solid white. Right now I am forced to have two style sheets - main.css for the gradient background, then internal.css for the internal - just for this background div.

Is there a way to use one css file and handle these two background divs easily? I will probably need to use a bit of php...

Essentially I am only trying to pass two different background divs, on either home or some internal pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use your normal stylsheet on all the pages, with the solid white background set. Then on your front page and other 'special' pages, you could have a  tag with the background image that will override the white:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" /><!-- This has background-color:white; -->
<?php if(!empty($special)){
echo <<<HTML
    <style>
    body{
        background-color:transparent;
        background-image:url('image_url');
    }
    </style>
HTML;
?>
</head>
```

Then you'd just set $special to true or something when you're on a 'special' page.

Comment: Thanks for your help! In Wordpress, since it generates the pages dynamically, how would i assign the 'special' pages?

Answer (score 2):

Just use different template files (which you should be doing anyway because of the different looks), and use something like an ID on the body tag to check like this:

```
<body id="grad">
    ...
</body>
```

or

```
<body id="white">
    ...
</body>
```

And use this in your stylesheet:

```
#grad {
    background-image:url(something.png);
}
#white {
    background-color:#FFF;
}
```

Make sure to check out the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Templates_Hierarchy) page in the WordPress codex to see how you can easily create the template files you need.  Use #grad in home.php and/or a custom template file that you apply to your front page (if it's static), and then use #while in everything else (category.php, tag.php, single.php, and page.php are probably the basics).

Comment: how would this work if the header is the file that display the body tag?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    if(is_home) {
        echo '<div class="bg for main page">';
    } else {
        echo '<div class="bg for internal page">';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think of this but here is the code:

```
<body<?php if ( !is_home() ) echo ' style="background-image: url(images/about_bg.png);"'; ?>>
```

Put it in the header.